# Fetching data from other model Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a user model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    username : DS.attr('string'),
    numberOfQuotes: DS.attr('number'),
    numberOfFollowers: DS.attr('number'),
    numberOfFollowing: DS.attr('number')
});
```

and a quotes model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
text: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And i am getting quotes which also includes the user id and for this i am using

`quotes :this.store.findAll('quote')`
But i am unable to get the user object so i am unable to retreive the data. Any help will work thanks.

Comment: are you fetching data from `server` or `ember local store` ? If from `server` could you please provide an example of the JSON response? Does your server response includes `user` object ?

Comment: i am getting from ember local store.

Comment: i modified my answer. please have a check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) From ember local store:

if you want to get the data from ember store you have to use `peekAll`. Use computed property in your controller or component,

```
...
quotes: computed(function() {
  return this.store.peekAll('quote');
}),
...
```

Then you can fetch the user data in your template as follows,

```
{{#each quotes as |quote|}}
  {{quote.user.username}}
{{/each}}
```

2) From server:

note: `findAll` query expects the data to be in array.

when using RESTAdapter,

```
{ quotes:
  [ {
     id: 1,
     text: "sample1",
     user: { username: "name1", numberOfQuotes: "5" }
    },
    {
     id: 2,
     text: "sample2",
     user: { username: "name2", numberOfQuotes: "8" }
    }
  ]
}
```

when using JSONAPIAdpater,

```
{ quotes:
  [ {
     id: 1,
     text: "sample1",
     user: 10
    },
    {
     id: 2,
     text: "sample2",
     user: 11
    },
    {
     id: 3,
     text: "sample3",
     user: 10
    }
  ],
  users:
  [ {
     id: 10,
     username: "name1",
     numberOfQuotes: "5"
     quotes: [1,3]
    },
    {
     id: 11,
     username: "name2",
     numberOfQuotes: "8"
     quotes: [2]
    }
  ]
}
```

When executing `findAll` query in your route model hook, any one of the above will be the kind of response you will be getting based on the APIAdapter you use.

```
...
model: function() {
  return this.store.findAll('quote');
}
...
```

Comment: What if i had data in ```  {
        id:1,
        text:"Hi I am working on Ember 3",
        user:1
    },
    {
        id:2,
        text:"Ember 2.0 is cool!",
        user:1
    },
    { 
      id: 3, 
      text: 'Hello one more time!',
      user: 1,
    } ```` and i wanted to get data of user using user id

Comment: have modified the answer as per your request. Please have a look at `http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/` and choose which adapter you are using and check what is the expected response data that ember expects.